# how to resolve download.file () function error

Tags: r

I have never had this problem before and it's infuriating.
this is my very straightforward code:

```
url <- "https://dax-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/dax-airline/1.0.1/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz"
download.file(url,"C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz")
```

and over and over I get this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, "C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz") :
  URL https://dax-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/dax-airline/1.0.1/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz: cannot open destfile 'C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz', reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In download.file(url, "C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

I tried setting the file path like this

```
download.file(url,"./C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz")
```

but I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, "./C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz") :
  URL https://dax-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/dax-airline/1.0.1/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz: cannot open destfile './C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz', reason 'Invalid argument'
2: In download.file(url, "./C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

i do not know what i am doing wrong. writing the code like this `download.file(url,"./lax_to_jfk.tar.gz")` also produces the same first error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, "C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz") :
  URL https://dax-cdn.cdn.appdomain.cloud/dax-airline/1.0.1/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz: cannot open destfile 'C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz', reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In download.file(url, "C:/Users/user/Documents/lax_to_jfk.tar.gz") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

Comment: Please confirm that `dir.exists("C:/Users/user/Documents/")` returns true

Comment: it does @r2evans